# Jquery multiple versions noConflict does not works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I working with jquery 1.8.3 and 1.10.2 in same page. But i can not use noConflict method of Jquery. 
1.10.2 for [Stickynavbar](http://www.jozefbutko.com/stickynavbar/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
$(function () {
    $('.header-bottom').stickyNavbar({
    activeClass: "active",          // Class to be added to highlight nav
```

Comment: show your code first then it may possible to give you an exact answer.

Comment: I added starts of code @Dipakchavda

Comment: can you post whole html?

Comment: How can i do that. Stackoverflow does not allow it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is the way where you can avoid jquery multiple versions conflict

```
<!-- load jQuery 1.8.3 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_8_3 = $.noConflict(true);
(function($){
    // here $ points to the old jQuery
})(jQuery_1_8_3);
</script>

<!-- load jQuery 1.10.2 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_10_2 = $.noConflict(true);
(function($){
    // here $ points to the old jQuery
})(jQuery_1_10_2);
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry i was wrong i tryed again with your edit it working now Much Thanks :)

Comment: Can you give a reputation. This subject does'nt find with google